# Xamarin: Binding objective c protocols that return protocols

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have the following 2 protocols in my app:

```
@protocol DisplayItem<NSObject>

- (void) itemSelected:(NSString*) itemId;

@end

@protocol DisplayerFactory <NSObject>

- (UIViewController<DisplayItem>*) createItemDisplayer;

@end
```

I use Objective Sharpie to bind them and I get the following binding:

```
// @protocol DisplayItem <NSObject>
[Protocol, Model]
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface DisplayItem
{
    // @required -(void)itemSelected:(NSString *)itemId;
    [Abstract]
    [Export("itemSelected:")]
    void ItemSelected(string itemId);
}

// @protocol DisplayerFactory <NSObject>
[Protocol, Model]
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface DisplayerFactory
{
    // @required -(UIViewController<DisplayItem> *)createItemDisplayer;
    [Abstract]
    [Export("createItemDisplayer")]
    DisplayItem CreateItemDisplayer();
}
```

That looks reasonable. Except now when I try to implement a `DisplayerFactory`, the `CreateItemDisplayer` method needs to return a `DisplayItem` and a `UIViewController`. Since `DisplayItem` is implemented as a class and we can't have multiple inheritance in C#, I can't have a class that inherits from both `UIViewController` and `DisplayItem`.

I tried using `IDisplayItem` as follows:

```
public class MyController : UIViewController, IDisplayItem
{
   // ...
}

public DisplayItem CreateItemDisplayer()
{
  return new MyController();
}
```

But that fails to compile because `MyController` is not a `DisplayItem`. If I change the method type to `IDisplayItem`, it fails to compile because I don't implement the `IDisplayerFactory` interface correctly (or override DisplayerFactory).

How do I resolve this so that I can return a `UIViewController` that implements the protocol.

Comment: Shooting in the dark here as a C# and Objective-C programmer.  In general you want to program to interfaces right?  Objective-C's patterns of "This is a view controller, but my protocol says it has some other methods, and that's super convenient" doesn't quite translate to C# really well.  You could have CreateItemDisplayer return something that's just id<DisplayItem> - Does the consumer care that it needs to be a UIViewController?  If it does - a hack could be having DisplayItem have a method that returns a UIViewController and just "return self;"  Try to redesign a bit to code to interfaces.

Comment: Yes the consumer does care that it be a UIViewController, it needs to be displayed. The consumer also cares that it implement DisplayItem since it needs to display the given item. This is programming to interfaces. The problem is that Xamarin binds protocols to abstract classes and not to interfaces. So it is not possible for my UIViewController to implement DisplayItem in Xamarin.

Answer (score 4):

Bind it like this:

```
interface IDisplayItem {}

// @protocol DisplayerFactory <NSObject>
[Protocol, Model]
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface DisplayerFactory
{
    // @required -(UIViewController<DisplayItem> *)createItemDisplayer;
    [Abstract]
    [Export("createItemDisplayer")]
    IDisplayItem CreateItemDisplayer();
}
```

and now this code will work, since `CreateItemDisplayer` returns an interface:

```
public class MyController : UIViewController, IDisplayItem
{
   // ...
}

public IDisplayItem CreateItemDisplayer()
{
  return new MyController();
}
```